# two slideshows at same time are not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am struggeling to make **both** slideshows working at the *same* time.

Do I need a seperate `JavaScript` for each one? All images that are one seperate slideshow are within a `<div>` with the class `instagram-slideshow`. How do I do multiple automatic slideshows on one page?

```js
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
  }, 500);
});

var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 2000);
}

(function($) {
  $.fn.visible = function(partial) {

    var $t = $(this),
      $w = $(window),
      viewTop = $w.scrollTop(),
      viewBottom = viewTop + $w.height(),
      _top = $t.offset().top,
      _bottom = _top + $t.height(),
      compareTop = partial === true ? _bottom : _top,
      compareBottom = partial === true ? _top : _bottom;

    return ((compareBottom <= viewBottom) && (compareTop >= viewTop));

  };

})(jQuery);

var win = $(window);

var allModifications = $(".half-width-content");


//make all elements visible that are directly visible
allModifications.each(function(i, el) {
  var el = $(el);
  if (el.visible(true)) {
    alert();
    el.find(".half-width-text").addClass("open");
  }
});


//make elements visible that get scrolled into the viewport
win.scroll(function(event) {

  allModifications.each(function(i, el) {
    var el = $(el);
    if (el.visible(true)) {
      el.find(".half-width-text").addClass("open");
    }
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container>div {
  min-height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container>div>a>.dot {
  position: relative;
  transition: background .2s linear;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 10%;
  z-index: 101;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.container>div>a>.dot>.arrow-down {
  transition: border .2s linear;
  position: absolute;
  top: 11%;
  left: 24%;
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}

.container>div>a .dot:hover {
  background: black;
}

.container>div>a .dot:hover>.arrow-down {
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}

.container>div>a>.dot>.arrow-down {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.container>div .content {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.full-width {
  width: 100%;
}

.half-width {
  width: 50%;
}

div>.content {
  background: green;
}

.video-iframe.fullsize {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.list {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.half-width>.half-width-content {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.half-width>.half-width-content>.instagram-slideshow {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.half-width>.half-width-content>.instagram-slideshow>img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.half-width>.half-width-content>.half-width-text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 150%;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: all 1s linear;
}

.half-width>.half-width-content>.half-width-text>h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.half-width>.half-width-content>.half-width-text.open {
  visibility: visible;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="full-width">
    <!--<iframe class="video-iframe fullsize" src="example_vid_this_snippet_works_except_the_vieo" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>-->
    <a href="#section2">
      <span class="dot">
        <i class="arrow-down"></i>
      </span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="half-width" id="section2">
    <div class="half-width-content">
      <div class="half-width-text">
        <h1>This is a headline</h1>
        <div class="text-content">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no
            sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="half-width">
    <div class="half-width-content">
      <div class="instagram-slideshow">
        <img class="slide" src="http://placekitten.com/200/300">
        <img class="slide" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/animals">
        <img class="slide" src="http://placekitten.com/200/300">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="half-width">
    <div class="half-width-content">
      <div class="instagram-slideshow">
        <img class="slide" src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/?text=Hello">
        <img class="slide" src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/?text=Bye">
        <img class="slide" src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/?text=BLA">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="half-width">
    div 4
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you fixed your code snippet? the are an error . The resource cannot be found

Comment: Yea i stated it. The question is about the slideshows, so I removed the youtube video to avoid issues. The snippet is working, except the iframe

Comment: Ok Bro, first of all you gave the second slides no class of slide, but the link of the source as a class, fix that and you'll be halfway through. Another problem might appear, if you call the slides sliedes as well, since it will count all slides in your js so you'll exceed 4 Slides per show which results in nothing to show after number 4.

Comment: I missed this on copy paste, I will fix it now. But adding the class will also result in not working properly, because all of them are displayed afterwards, so if the first one is finished, the second one starts

Comment: no offense but it looks like that you don't have much of an idea what you are doing/copying.
The snippet you are using will not work for 2 slideshows because it does not init any slideshow-object (or so) on a wrapper-div. It just takes ALL objects with the class `slide` and makes 1 huge slideshow out of these. You'll have to limit the `showSlides()` function to some wrapper-element and then init the slideshow for every wrapper-element separately

Comment: thats why I asked:)

Comment: please web developers, understand what you do, frameworks and libraries are good, if you understand it.

Comment: ? the slideshow is in pure javascript

Comment: when I see $ everywhere in your javascript .... @ItFreak

Comment: thats for the slide in of the divs and registering slide animations on a tags that link to an in-page element?

Comment: so why is it here, in your question about making the slideshow works, your piece of code si too long...

Comment: because then some people would state that the piece does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go

```js
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
  }, 500);
});

var slideIndex = 0;

// run TWO slideshows, one for each slider
showSlides(0);
showSlides(1);

// give your slider function parameter of index
function showSlides(index) {
  var i;
  // select the particular slider and THEN its slides
  var sliderBlock = document.getElementsByClassName("instagram-slideshow")[index];
  var slides = sliderBlock.getElementsByClassName("slide");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  // after timeout run appropriate function again
  setTimeout(function() {showSlides(index)}, 2000);
}

(function($) {
  $.fn.visible = function(partial) {

    var $t = $(this),
      $w = $(window),
      viewTop = $w.scrollTop(),
      viewBottom = viewTop + $w.height(),
      _top = $t.offset().top,
      _bottom = _top + $t.height(),
      compareTop = partial === true ? _bottom : _top,
      compareBottom = partial === true ? _top : _bottom;

    return ((compareBottom <= viewBottom) && (compareTop >= viewTop));

  };

})(jQuery);

var win = $(window);

var allModifications = $(".half-width-content");


//make all elements visible that are directly visible
allModifications.each(function(i, el) {
  var el = $(el);
  if (el.visible(true)) {
    alert();
    el.find(".half-width-text").addClass("open");
  }
});


//make elements visible that get scrolled into the viewport
win.scroll(function(event) {

  allModifications.each(function(i, el) {
    var el = $(el);
    if (el.visible(true)) {
      el.find(".half-width-text").addClass("open");
    }
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container>div {
  min-height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container>div>a>.dot {
  position: relative;
  transition: background .2s linear;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 10%;
  z-index: 101;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.container>div>a>.dot>.arrow-down {
  transition: border .2s linear;
  position: absolute;
  top: 11%;
  left: 24%;
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}

.container>div>a .dot:hover {
  background: black;
}

.container>div>a .dot:hover>.arrow-down {
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}

.container>div>a>.dot>.arrow-down {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.container>div .content {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.full-width {
  width: 100%;
}

.half-width {
  width: 50%;
}

div>.content {
  background: green;
}

.video-iframe.fullsize {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.list {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.half-width>.half-width-content {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.half-width>.half-width-content>.instagram-slideshow {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.half-width>.half-width-content>.instagram-slideshow>img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.half-width>.half-width-content>.half-width-text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 150%;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: all 1s linear;
}

.half-width>.half-width-content>.half-width-text>h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.half-width>.half-width-content>.half-width-text.open {
  visibility: visible;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="full-width">
    <!--<iframe class="video-iframe fullsize" src="example_vid_this_snippet_works_except_the_vieo" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>-->
    <a href="#section2">
      <span class="dot">
        <i class="arrow-down"></i>
      </span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="half-width" id="section2">
    <div class="half-width-content">
      <div class="half-width-text">
        <h1>This is a headline</h1>
        <div class="text-content">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no
            sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="half-width">
    <div class="half-width-content">
      <div class="instagram-slideshow">
        <img class="slide" src="http://placekitten.com/200/300">
        <img class="slide" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/animals">
        <img class="slide" src="http://placekitten.com/200/300">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="half-width">
    <div class="half-width-content">
      <div class="instagram-slideshow">
        <img class="slide" src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/?text=Hello">
        <img class="slide" src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/?text=Bye">
        <img class="slide" src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/?text=BLA">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="half-width">
    div 4
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Straight solution and commented changes. Keep it going!

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for, a commented correction!

Answer (score 1):

Please, Javascript Vanilla (Pure JS) can do it all alone and very simply, this is my example of the most simple code to write a slideshow : https://jsfiddle.net/ya3wk9ro/30/ and all is needed is few lines of Javascript.

Of course you can add some animation features but this is the basics.

```
'
```